# JPA deleting children ONLY, not parent, in OneToOne

Tags: jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I had a quick question about ORM relationships with JPA Spring Data.

I have

AuthToken.java:

```
@OneToOne(optional=true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="authToken")
private User user;
```

User.java:

```
@OneToOne(optional=true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(
      name="authorizationId", unique=true, nullable=true, updatable=true)
private AuthorizationToken authToken;
```

My point here is the AuthToken should be nulled out when the token has expired.

Trying to use CrudRepository to delete leads to "constraint/foreignkey" errors because it tries to delete BOTH PARENT+CHILD using CascadeType.ALL.

I just want the TOKEN (child) to delete, not the user.

Is there a proper way to write this out?

What I ended up doing is: `Usr.setToken(null); UserRepo.save(Usr);`

I can't use AuthRepo.delete or AuthRepo.save anything like that.

Using "delete" doesn't work right.

Comment: First you can remove the FetchType because the default is already EAGER, according to the mapped by must be the name of the attribute authorizationToken

Comment: Why do you set cascade to ALL if you do **not** want to cascade the deletion?

Comment: @Ulisses yes but that was correct in the code. sure I can remove eager if its default.

Comment: @JBNizet because I still want them "unlinked". As in, when I do authRepo.find, I should no longer see a user for it. Or userRepo.find, i should no longer see an authToken associated with it. How else without cascading delete?

Comment: @Dexter In Jpa everything that ends with "toOne" defaults to "FetchType" "Eager", and everything ending with "toMany" defaults to "FetchType" "Lazy"

Comment: If A.b has cascade=DELETE (or ALL), it means that deleting a will also delete b. You have cascade in the two directions, so deleting a user will also delete its authToken, and deleting an authToken will delete its user. But anyway, if you want to keep the user, but delete the authToken, you MUST set user.authToken to null before deleting the authToke, since it has a foreign key pointing to it.

Comment: @JBNizet  see that's what i was missing. I did change the CascadeType to not have delete for one direction but when that didn't work i was confused. But it appears I am missing this last part "null" for usr.authToken=null before authRepo.delete. You should write an answer.

Comment: @Dexter, so... add in the AuthToken entity the CascadeType.DETACH

Comment: you guys want credit for answer? Thanks to both of you either way.